# Use external method in Linq orderBy

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I would like to orderBy list by ShortName and then by phone number. Firstly show records with phoneNumber then without.

I tried:

```
var x = q.OrderByDescending(e => e.ShortName).ThenBy(c => SqlFunctions.IsNumeric(Order(c)));

private string Order(Contractor c)
{
    var phoneNumber = c.Contacts.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == c.LeadingContact)?.PhoneNumber ?? "";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber) || phoneNumber.Equals("---"))
        return "a";
    return "1";
}
```

but in result i get:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Order(DOCR.Domain.Entities.CRM.Contractor)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Has anyone idea how to workaround this?

Comment: It should work.  I used similar code lots of times.  Looks like it is looking for method in System.String class instead of your class either try to make public or include the namespace before the method Order.

Comment: It should work but as a side note that linq sort is not that great. You could start by removing the `SqlFunctions` all together and just return `Order` and change `Order` to return an `int` and set the value to `0` or `1` instead and it will use an `integer` sort normally.

Comment: You tagged this as LINQ to Entities - is `q` a database query? If so, you can't use local methods in queries that must translate to a database query - the code can't run on the SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account the suggestions from the comments, I tried to think about it and worked out a working but propably not the most effective solution for the problem. Below code stands for `.OrderByDescening` firstly by first letter of short name and then place at the end items which leading contact has no phone number (knowing that no phone number can also be entered as `"---"`.

```
var x = q.OrderByDescending(e => e.ShortName.Substring(0, 1))
.ThenBy(c => (c.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == c.LeadingContact).PhoneNumber ?? "---").Equals("---") ? 1 : 0);
```

If u has knowledge how to optimize or write it better, I would appreciate your suggestions